# What tools,methods, etc. Can I use for advanced prototyping?

Tags: tools, prototype

So, I am working on this product and I have been asked to do an advanced prototype where the user can select a particular choice from a drop down menu, add text, hovers, etc. I downloaded Axure and I made a prototype with the invision app, but does anyone here know any other tool which would help me?

P.s I haven't used Axure, if someone has, I would love to get some feedback on it.

Comment: Please give more information about your aims and your utility. Is it just for this current product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used these tools before therefore I would recommend using them for wireframing and prototyping.

**Wireframing**

1. [Sketch](http://www.sketchapp.com/)
2. [Balsamiq](https://balsamiq.com/)
3. [Mockingbird](https://gomockingbird.com/home) (Free)
4. [Framebox](http://framebox.org/) (Free)

**Prototyping**

1. [FramerJS](http://framerjs.com/)
2. [Flinto](https://www.flinto.com/mac) (iphone)
3. [Proto.io](https://proto.io/) (iphone)
4. [Marvel](https://marvelapp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a heavy user of both Axure and InVision.

Axure is the industry standard for building clickable prototypes because it will do anything you can think of if you have enough patience. For the examples you've given - building interactions based on dropdown options and hover states it's a very strong choice.

InVision works differently in that you use hotspots to link together screens designed in a wireframing or design tool (I'd recommend Sketch). You can achieve the same interactions but it's a more laborious task - you'll have to design the open dropdown and link to it when the user clicks the closed dropdown; it's not as simple as adding some options to the dropdown control.

In short, if prototyping is your only goal then Axure is a great choice but if you have other requirements - version control, the ability to design high fidelity comps and generate production assets etc. you might want to consider something else - like Sketch/Photoshop with InVision or Marvel.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the feedback. I have one question: I have to create a high fidelity advanced prototype, but I'm kinda stuck because I don't know if I should import the UI elements I already created in Photoshop to Axure, or create the shapes inside Axure and go from there creating the whole prototype from there?

Comment: Do you have any tutorial that would guide me through creating an advanced prototype,how to begin,etc.